# Making Materialize slider responsive

Tags: css, slider, materialize, responsive-slides

I'm trying to make Materialize slider responsive using a CSS, but it's doesn't work properly. when I test my code with the adaptive view of Firefox, I get slider images responsive with a grey background much bigger than the height of the slider images(as you can see below).

```css
   .slider .slides li img {

background-size: 100% auto;;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="slider " >
  <ul class="slides ">
                <li>
      <img class="responsive-img" id="img" src="{{ asset('font/images/IMG_61.jpg') }}"> 
    </li>
      <li>
      <img class="responsive-img" id="img" src="{{ asset('font/images/IMG_53.jpg') }}"> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="responsive-img" id="img" src="{{ asset('font/images/IMG_2.jpg') }}"> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[screen shot  size 360×640](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3vO.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, works for me

```
 .slider .slides {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0;
    height: 400px;
}

.slider .slides li img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This makes the image responsive, but the slider not as it relies on fixed height (css & js), which means it will keep borders / margins on top / bottom while image shrinks together with browser window ... I am starting to regret by moving away from Bootstrap

Comment: ya, i was also trying but same problem so i have tried few fixes to work for me

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution that worked for me:
Manually assigning the height for the slider as 250px for small and medium-sized devices and 600px slider height for large devices (devices with more than 600px width)

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
          .slides {
            height: 250px !important;
          }
            .slider {
                 height: 250px !important;
            }
        }

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
          .slides {
            height: 600px !important;
          }
            .slider {
                 height: 600px !important;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I am a newbie in writing answers in StackOverflow. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You literally have add:

```
.fullscreen
```

to the slider and this works, as shown in the documentation. Patience to read people, that's all it takes :)

https://materializecss.com/fullscreen-slider-demo.html

Codepen showing markup and initialisation:

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/YzXqdPO

```
<div class="slider fullscreen">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="active" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464817739973-0128fe77aaa1?dpr=1&amp;auto=compress,format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1199&amp;h=799&amp;q=80&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;crop=&quot;);"> <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption center-align" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
        <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1414849424631-8b18529a81ca?q=75&amp;fm=jpg&amp;s=0e993004a2f3704e8f2ad5469315ccb7&quot;);"> <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption left-align" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateX(-100px);">
        <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://ununsplash.imgix.net/uploads/1413259835094dcdeb9d3/6e609595?q=75&amp;fm=jpg&amp;s=6a4fc66161293fc4a43a6ca6f073d1c5&quot;);"> <!-- random image -->
      <div class="caption right-align" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateX(100px);">
        <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
<ul class="indicators"><li class="indicator-item active"></li><li class="indicator-item"></li><li class="indicator-item"></li></ul></div>
```